# How to fail an ant build if dependent packages have classes with same namespace

Tags: java, kotlin, build, ant

We have a plugin based architecture for our service , where we have a dependency on every plugin package that we support.
We recently encountered a problem where at runtime we get errors like enum attributes not found because plugins have enums/classes with same package name and class name. How can we write some tests or fail ANT build if plugins have classes/enums with same package name and class name.

Answer (score 0):

A code example to iterate through jar files of a plugin directory and find package duplicates.

```
public class JarDuplicatePackageTest {
private static Map<String, Integer> packageCount = new HashMap<>();

static class JarFileFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith("jar");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        File pluginsDirectory = new File("plugins");
        FilenameFilter filter = new JarFileFilter();
        File[] files = pluginsDirectory.listFiles(filter);

        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            JarInputStream jarInputStream = new JarInputStream(fileInputStream);

            while(jarInputStream.getNextEntry() != null) {
                JarEntry entry = jarInputStream.getNextJarEntry();

                // list the contents of the jar file 
                System.out.println(entry.toString());

                if(entry.toString().endsWith("class")) {
                    int incremented = 1;
                    if(packageCount.containsKey(entry.toString())) {
                        incremented = packageCount.get(entry.toString()) + 1;
                    }
                    packageCount.put(entry.toString(), incremented);
                }
            }
            jarInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
        }

        packageCount.forEach((k, v) -> {
            if(v > 1){ System.out.println("Duplicate: " + k );}
        });

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}